# How could the make function work inside the Bash loop running in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

How could the make function work inside the Bash loop, tried :

```
Part=hey high huh
Str=hey do not be high huh
entity:
    @for n in $(Part) ;{ \
      echo $(subst $$n,,$(Str)); \
    }
```

to remove certain strings.. do not work, how to solve it?

Comment: The correct for-in loop syntax is `for ... in ...; do ...; done`

Comment: Do you really want n strings with one of the `Part` elements removed in each or do you want to remove all at once?

Comment: If your make recipe does not work and you want to find out why, first remove the `@` in front of the line so you can see the actual shell command make runs. You might even add a `set -x; ` in front of the command to have the shell echo every command it executes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` is executed by the shell, and `$(subst ...)` is a make function, thus will be executed before the shell has a chance to loop.  You'll have to get the equivalent function in shell.  For instance

```
Part=hey high huh
Str=hey do not be high huh
entity:
        @for n in $(Part) ; do \
            echo $$(echo $(Str) | sed "s/$$n//") ; \
        done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution inside make:

```
Part=hey high huh
Str=hey do not be high huh
entity:
    $(foreach p,$(Part),echo $(filter-out $(p),$(Str));)
```

Notice the `;` before the closing `)` which serves to separate the `echo` commands as they will be executed in one line of the shell. If the shell commands get more complicated than a simple `echo`, you may be better off with a full-blown [canned recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canned-Recipes.html).